# Firebase Messages don't work

Tags: java, android, token, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new in Android, my android app crashes when I try to send a message with Firebase.
Any ideas?

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**RegistrationIntentService.java:**

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


// abbreviated tag name
static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);


    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));

}

private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("BookStore")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.book)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }


}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
    Process: gamingproject.sellmybooks, PID: 20478
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzUr()Landroid/content/Intent; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver' appears in /data/app/gamingproject.sellmybooks-2/base.apk)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3055)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:163)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1456)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
07-09 14:14:24.634 970-22768/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
07-09 14:14:24.634 970-22768/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
07-09 14:14:24.834 2415-22773/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on crash_info_summary(package_name_touched)
07-09 14:14:24.904 2415-22773/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on crash_info_summary(package_name_touched)
07-09 14:14:25.244 20342-20342/? E/WidgetProviderAssistiveLight: buildUpdate PORTRAIT
07-09 14:14:27.314 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:29.454 970-997/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-09 14:14:29.454 970-997/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-09 14:14:29.454 970-997/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-09 14:14:29.454 970-997/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-09 14:14:29.484 22805-22805/? E/Zygote: v2
07-09 14:14:29.504 22805-22805/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-09 14:14:29.704 22805-22805/gamingproject.sellmybooks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: gamingproject.sellmybooks, PID: 22805
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzUr()Landroid/content/Intent; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver' appears in /data/app/gamingproject.sellmybooks-2/base.apk)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3055)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:163)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1456)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)
07-09 14:14:29.714 970-22837/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
07-09 14:14:29.714 970-22837/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
07-09 14:14:29.794 2415-22838/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on crash_info_summary(package_name_touched)
07-09 14:14:29.834 2415-22838/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on crash_info_summary(package_name_touched)
07-09 14:14:30.214 970-1256/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 473
07-09 14:14:30.314 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:33.314 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:36.314 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:39.314 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:42.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:45.314 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:48.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:51.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:54.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:14:56.004 970-1006/? E/PowerManagerService: handleSandman : startDreaming, but isDreaming false
07-09 14:14:56.164 970-1040/? E/lights: write_int failed to open -1
07-09 14:14:56.214 970-1070/? E/native: do suspend true
07-09 14:14:56.344 245-245/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
07-09 14:14:56.344 245-245/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
07-09 14:14:56.564 245-578/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
07-09 14:14:56.564 245-578/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
07-09 14:14:57.004 1778-1778/? E/LibSecureUISvc: svc_sock_send_message(suisvc): Error sending data, -1 vs 4: Connection refused
07-09 14:14:57.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:15:00.214 970-1256/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 474
07-09 14:15:00.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
07-09 14:15:01.064 1137-1137/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
07-09 14:15:03.324 268-268/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
```

**gradle**:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

    // Dependency for Google Sign-In
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'

    //Facebook Login
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.2'

    // Dependency for Google Messages
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A crash is always written to the LogCat and while we're potentially able to spot the error in your code the actual stacktrace is a thousand times more helpful. Please retrieve it and edit your question.

Comment: Yes, I have logcat but I don't understand this

Comment: Post up your gradle file, you're probably missing a firebase lib.

Comment: I've done. any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution, I have written this in my gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

instead of this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi Cario, 9.2.0 is the recommended version of the firebase-messaging SDK, can you clarify which version you are using?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError can indicate that the device does not yet have the latest version of Google Play services installed. Could you confirm the version of Google Play services installed on the device, it should be 9.2.x

Answer (score 0):

This was a while ago, but here is the solution:

In the manifest, instead of:

`<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>`

Use

`<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>`